# How do I get the window size in visionOS?

Tags: swift, swiftui, visionos

Is there something similar to `UIScreen.main.bounds` on visionOS?

I have some code that depends on the screen size and using a hard coded value for it doesn’t really work out unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried utilizing [GeometryReader](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryreader)

Comment: Use `SwiftUI.Layout` or `GeometryReader` depending on the scenario

Comment: I'd recommend to look into containerRelativeFrame for iOS 17+ and visionOS https://developer.apple.com/documentation/deviceactivity/deviceactivityreport/containerrelativeframe(_:alignment:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't exist on visionOS. UIScreen and UIWindow are different classes on iOS, and while there are UIWindows on visionOS, there's no analog of UIScreen (the class itself in marked `unavailable`). The visionOS 'screen' is not really measured in points, but in degrees of field-of-view, and as such, you can't really convert between the two. You can always get the size of the current window by using a GeometryReader.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's official documentation states that the [default window size](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/windows#visionOS) in visionOS is `1280x720` pt. At the moment, there is no way to measure visionOS window size using `.bounds` property, however, to measure the size, you can use `GeometryReader3D`.

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader3D { proxy3D in
        VStack {
            RealityView { content in
                // code here...
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            Task {
                try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
                print("The size is:", proxy3D.size)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
//  The size is: (width: 1280.0, height: 720.0, depth: 540.0)
```

**P. S.**

A default size for a volumetric window is `1280x1280x1280` pt.

Comment: For me `GeometryReader3D` isn't even working to give the window size of a volumetric window: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77970699/geometryreader3d-always-reading-1280x1280x1280-in-a-volumetric-window-on-visiono