# What units are used in VisionOS?

Tags: realitykit, visionos

This is a broad question but I think its worth asking. What units are used in the various parts of VisionOS?

I've been playing around with volumetric windows, immersive spaces, WindowGroups, GeometryReader, and GeometryReader3D and its difficult to figure out which element is using pixels and which element is using meters.

On a similar note, you can set the `position` of RealityView content but that's also hard because `position` is set in pixels (?) and the 3-dimensional space is measured in meters.

Answer (score 1):

## Units

| Name | Platform | Units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Windows | VisionOS | [Points](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/windows) |
| Volumes | VisionOS | Points |
| WindowGroup | VisionOS | Points |
| GeometryReader | All | Points |
| ModelEntity | RealityKit | [Meters](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/605/?time=280) |
|  | ARKit | [Meters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51760421/which-measuring-unit-is-used-in-scnvector3-position-for-x-y-and-z-in-arkit#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=In%20ARKit%20the%20unit%20of,Y%2CZ%20axis%20intersect) |

You can set the units for a WindowGroup using the "in" property of the `.defaultSize` modifier like this:

```
WindowGroup {
            HourglassView()
        }.windowStyle(.volumetric)
            .defaultSize(width: 2000, height: 4000, depth: 2000, in: .centimeters)
```

## Bonus

"By default, a [window](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/windows) measures 1280x720 pt. When a window first opens, the system places it about two meters in front of the wearer, giving it an apparent width of about three meters."

The default size for a volumetric window is [1280x1280x1280](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77221392/12806961). Refer to this [article](https://www.createwithswift.com/configuring-default-window-and-volume-size-in-visionos/) for more info.